# I need to run an OS command with python but python execute a new line

Tags: python, paramiko

I need to run the following command into a Paramiko SSH COnnection

`dpkg-deb -I /opt/test/one.deb | grep -E "Depends|Recommends|Suggests|Pre\-Depends" | tr -d "|," | sed "s/([^)]*)/()/g" | tr -d "()" | tr " " "\n" | grep -Ev "Depends|Recommends|Suggests|Pre\-Depends" | xargs'`

The problem is that python execute the "\n" and break the command. So, python only send the following chunk: `dpkg-deb -I /opt/test/one.deb | grep -E "Depends|Recommends|Suggests|Pre\-Depends" | tr -d "|," | sed "s/([^)]*)/()/g" | tr -d "()" | tr " "`

I need that the "\n" will not be interpreted and send it as part of the os command.

Comment: If that command is coming from a string literal in your code, you need to double that backslash character to escape it.

Comment: In addition to showing us the command, show us how your Python code is issuing that command. The problem is in the Python code, after all, so we need to see that.

Comment: Hi all, sorrry for the delay. The problem was solved with the double bar ( // ).
Thank you all!